# How to correctly implement Speech Recognition in Windows 10 UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

So far I haven't had any luck with the voice recognition examples that I have found on Microsoft's website. I have also looked at this website - https://mtaulty.com/2016/02/08/text-to-speech-and-more-with-windows-10-uwp-project-oxford/ and I tried using the examples given and it still doesn't work. What is happening is the SpeechRecognitionConfidence is rejected (it isn't picking up that I said anything). Before you ask, yes I have a working microphone and everything is enabled in Settings.

Is there something simple that I'm missing here?

If you don't quite understand my question scroll to the bottom of the page I linked above and user nhwilly1011 has the same issue I am experiencing.

```
async void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer();
        await this.recognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();

        this.recognizer.Timeouts.InitialSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        this.recognizer.Timeouts.EndSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);

        this.recognizer.UIOptions.AudiblePrompt = "Say whatever you like, I'm listening";
        this.recognizer.UIOptions.ExampleText = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
        this.recognizer.UIOptions.ShowConfirmation = true;
        this.recognizer.UIOptions.IsReadBackEnabled = true;
        this.recognizer.Timeouts.BabbleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

        var result = await this.recognizer.RecognizeWithUIAsync();

        if (result != null)
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            builder.AppendLine(
              $"I have {result.Confidence} confidence that you said [{result.Text}] " +
              $"and it took {result.PhraseDuration.TotalSeconds} seconds to say it " +
              $"starting at {result.PhraseStartTime:g}");

            var alternates = result.GetAlternates(10);

            builder.AppendLine(
              $"There were {alternates?.Count} alternates - listed below (if any)");

            if (alternates != null)
            {
                foreach (var alternate in alternates)
                {
                    builder.AppendLine(
                      $"Alternate {alternate.Confidence} confident you said [{alternate.Text}]");
                }
            }
            this.txtResults.Text = builder.ToString();
        }
    }
    SpeechRecognizer recognizer;
```

I have also tried the Microsoft example and it does not work either --

```
    private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create an instance of SpeechRecognizer.
        var speechRecognizer = new Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognizer();

        //// Listen for audio input issues.
        //speechRecognizer.RecognitionQualityDegrading += speechRecognizer_RecognitionQualityDegrading;

        // Add a web search grammar to the recognizer.
        var webSearchGrammar = new Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognitionTopicConstraint(Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognitionScenario.WebSearch, "webSearch");


        speechRecognizer.UIOptions.AudiblePrompt = "Say what you want to search for...";
        speechRecognizer.UIOptions.ExampleText = @"Ex. 'weather for London'";
        speechRecognizer.Constraints.Add(webSearchGrammar);


        // Compile the constraint.
        await speechRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();

        // Start recognition.
        Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognitionResult speechRecognitionResult = await speechRecognizer.RecognizeWithUIAsync();
        await speechRecognizer.RecognizeWithUIAsync();

        // Do something with the recognition result.
        var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(speechRecognitionResult.Text, "Text spoken");
        await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
    }
```

Comment: please edit your question provide details of the error. The link to mtaulty.com can break after several years, so it is safer to include the  details in one place (in stackoverflow).

Comment: When the UI prompts the user to speak (and I say something) and it does not recognize what I have spoken. It recognizes that I have said something but it defaults the output of what was spoken to "".

Comment: @kennyzx I have added the code - thank you for the recommendation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found out the answer. My computer was not enabled with Cortana so I initially wasn't getting an error message. After using a computer that had Cortana I was able to figure out that there was an issue with the network that I was using. After switching networks everything worked as expected. My error was Error with speech recognition: "Can't access the network" and it was fixed by switching to an unsecured WiFi connection.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I've missed something, but before calling `CompileConstraintsAsync` it is recommended to add a `SpeechRecognitionTopicConstraint` to the Constraints collection of the `SpeechRecognizer`. 
Here is a helpful walk through I found, [here](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/05/16/using-speech-in-your-uwp-apps-its-good-to-talk/#5hFjcseoA1Qc72YB.97).

Comment: The example that I included does not have SpeechRecognitionTopicConstraint, however I have also tried the example off of Microsoft's website which does -- still doesn't work. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/speech-recognition  (the third example)

Comment: Are you getting the same issue with what is being recognized or are you getting another error?

Comment: Same issue with both -- they both don't pick up what is said but they do pick up that _something_ was said.

Answer (score 1):

HERE you may found the wake up word speech recoognization from Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition

```
    public MAINPage()
            {
     this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
    
    } 
Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognizer recognizer;
    public async void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
            {
                this.recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer();
    
                var commands = new Dictionary<string, int>()
                { 
                    [Constants.WAKEUP_INIT_WORD] = -90, //define your start word
                    [Constants.WAKEUP_STOP_WORD] = 90 //define your stop word
                };
    
                this.recognizer.Constraints.Add(new SpeechRecognitionListConstraint(
                  commands.Keys));
    
                await this.recognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();
    
                this.recognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.ResultGenerated +=
                  async (s, e) =>
                  {
                      if ((e.Result != null) && (commands.ContainsKey(e.Result.Text)))
                      {
                          await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                    () =>
                        {
                            
                            //e.Result.Confidence
                            double confidence = e.Result.RawConfidence;
                            if (e.Result.Confidence == SpeechRecognitionConfidence.Medium || e.Result.Confidence == SpeechRecognitionConfidence.High || confidence >0.85)
                            {
                                if (e.Result.Text == Constants.WAKEUP_INIT_WORD)
                                {
                                    recordButton_Click(sender, args);
                                    stopRecordButton.IsEnabled = true;
                                    recordButton.IsEnabled = false;
    
                                }
                                if (e.Result.Text == Constants.WAKEUP_STOP_WORD)
                                {
                                    stopRecordButton_Click(sender, args);
                                    recordButton.IsEnabled = true;
                                    stopRecordButton.IsEnabled = false;
                                }
                            }
    
                        }
                  );
                          this.recognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.Resume();
                      }
                  };
    
                await this.recognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.StartAsync(
                  SpeechContinuousRecognitionMode.PauseOnRecognition);
            }
enter code here
```

more varities are here https://mtaulty.com/2016/02/08/text-to-speech-and-more-with-windows-10-uwp-project-oxford/